# Are the units for the magnetic moment correct for this paper?

Tags: electromagnetism, dimensional-analysis, magnetic-moment, si-units

Can the units of $$\frac{e\,c}{2\pi\,f},$$ where $c$ is the speed of light, $e$ is the elementary charge and $f$ is the frequency, be correct for the magnetic moment?

I see that the units of magnetic moment should be $\text A \text m^2$
but when I look at this solution, it goes

$$\frac{\text C \frac{\text m}{\text s}}{\frac 1 s} = \frac{\text C}{\text s}  \text m  \text s = \text A \text m \text s.$$

Am I missing something or is this paper wrong? I am hoping the paper is correct and I am just missing something. Thanks

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281266794_Magnetic_Moment_of_Photon

Comment: Wolfram says its electric dipole moment

Comment: Even if the relevant equation appears in the abstract, you should paraphrase or directly quote (with citation) the segment of the paper you are referencing since not everyone might have access to this site.

Comment: Hi R. Emery, thanks! that's what i was looking for! i'll upvote your comment and mark it as correct once i can.

Comment: I looked briefly at that paper and am skeptical about its quality. (Actually I’m skeptical about the quality of anything published by [Scientific Research Publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Research_Publishing).) I suggest also reading [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjc/s10052-014-2899-y.pdf) about the photon magnetic moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wolfram says that

$$\frac{e\,c}{2\pi\,f}$$

is electric dipole moment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/326744)

Comment: I already did and he said it was the answer he was looking for. @GiorgioP

Comment: An answer should be something more than just a yes/no. A few words of explanation why you think that it is correct would make your post a real answer. Authority principle, even in the case of Wolfram, cannot be considered a strong argument.